How to run Firestore in Angular 17 with standalone components?
The default Component with Angular 17 is “Standalone”.
I would like to use Firestore in this context, but all the examples I could find are either
without Angular or with the older versions and app.module.
https://firebase.google.com/codelabs/firebase-web
is a very good tutorial, but it  was not updated to conform with “Standalone”.
The https://github.com/angular/angularfire has not been upgraded to Standalone.
Some asked a similar question here :
equivalent of "app.module.ts" in Angular 17?
but the answers were only how not to use standalone.
I hope  someone can tell me where I can find a tutorial or  a working example.

The providers need to be initialized during the bootstrap of the standalone component.
The injected Firestore dependency can then be used in the Standalone Component or a Component used by it
Stackblitz example
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { provideRouter } from '@angular/router';
import { routes } from './app.routes';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';
import { importProvidersFrom } from '@angular/core';
import {
  Firestore,
  collection,
  addDoc,
  getFirestore,
  provideFirestore,
} from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { initializeApp, provideFirebaseApp } from '@angular/fire/app';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [FormsModule],
  template: `
    <h1>Standalone Angular Firestore </h1>
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="inputValue" />
    <button (click)="add2Firestore(inputValue)">Add </button>
    <p>{{message}}</p>
  `,
})
export class App implements OnInit {
  name = 'Angular';
  inputValue = 'test data';
  message = '';
  count = 0;

  constructor(private firestore: Firestore) {}
  ngOnInit(): void {}

  add2Firestore(inputVal: string) {
    const test = collection(this.firestore, 'test');
    addDoc(test, { date: new Date(), test: inputVal + ' ' + this.count++,
    }).then((p) => {
      this.message = `id: ${p.id} added data: ${inputVal}`;
    });
    console.log(`Test data added ${inputVal}`);
  }
}

// Providers need to be initialized during the bootstrap of the standalone.
// Injected Firestore can then be used in the Standalone Component or a Component used by it
bootstrapApplication(App, {
  providers: [
    provideRouter(routes),
    importProvidersFrom(
      provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp(environment.firebase)),
      provideFirestore(() => getFirestore())
    ),
  ],
});


See HappyCoder link
How to integrate Angularfire (Angular binding for firebase) into a standalone Angular project
